# How is \obeylines different from \obeyspaces?

Tags: plain-tex

Let us look at dirty trick #3 in appendix D of *TeXbook*.

The following code produces space of category 12:

```
\def\uncatcodespecials{\def\do##1{\catcode`##1=12 }\dospecials}
\def\setupverbatim{\tt
  \obeylines
  \obeyspaces
  \uncatcodespecials
}
\def\listing#1{\par\begingroup\setupverbatim\input#1 \endgroup}
\listing{\jobname.tex}
\bye
```

This changes category of space to 13:

```
\def\uncatcodespecials{\def\do##1{\catcode`##1=12 }\dospecials}
\def\setupverbatim{\tt
  \obeylines
  \uncatcodespecials
  \obeyspaces
}
\def\listing#1{\par\begingroup\setupverbatim\input#1 \endgroup}
\listing{\jobname.tex}
\bye
```

From this we conclude that placing `\uncatcodespecials` after changing catcode changes it back to category 12, but placing `\uncatcodespecials` before changing catcode, does not influence it.

On the contrary, `\obeylines` stays in effect no matter where we put `\uncatcodespecials` - before or after it. How is `\obeylines` different from `\obeyspaces`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In `plain.tex`:

```
% Here is a list of the characters that have been specially catcoded:
\def\dospecials{\do\ \do\\\do\{\do\}\do\$\do\&%
  \do\#\do\^\do\^^K\do\_\do\^^A\do\%\do\~}
% (not counting ascii null, tab, linefeed, formfeed, return, delete)
% Each symbol in the list is preceded by \do, which can be defined
% if you want to do something to every item in the list.
```

On the other hand, `\obeylines` does

```
\catcode`\^^M\active \let^^M\par
```

where the definition is done with `^^M` active, for `\let^^M\par` to work.

The answer to your question is thus that the `\dospecials` invoked by your `\uncatcodespecials` does not change `\catcode13`, hence has no impact on the action of `\obeylines` even if issued after it. On the other hand it does change `\catcode32` hence cancels `\obeyspaces` (which does `` \catcode`\ \active ``) if issued after it.